# Скрипт с посылкой изображения по e-mail

Tags: php

Как в этом скрипте прописать ссылку на картинку так, чтобы картинка отправлялась по е-mail?

```
<?
define('SITE',true);
include("../admin/conf.php");
if($_GET['k']!=md5($c['admin_mail']))die();
$all=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jb_subscribe LIMIT ".$c['subscribe_limit']);cq();
$countmail=0;
while($d=mysql_fetch_assoc($all)){
    $subject=$c['subscribe_theme'];
    $subject=str_replace("[HOST]",$h,$subject);
    $subject=str_replace("[REGISTER_PAGE]",$h."register.html",$subject);
    $subject=str_replace("[USER_NAME]",$d['username'],$subject);
    $subject=str_replace("[USER_ADS]",$h."c".$d['id_cat']."-".$d['id_board'].".html",$subject);
    $msg=$c['subscribe_text'];
    $msg=str_replace("[HOST]",$h,$msg);
    $msg=str_replace("[REGISTER_PAGE]",$h."register.html",$msg);
    $msg=str_replace("[USER_NAME]",$d['username'],$msg);
    $msg=str_replace("[USER_ADS]",$h."c".$d['id_cat']."-".$d['id_board'].".html",$msg);
    $from=(@$c['subscribe_from']!="")?$c['subscribe_from']:$c['admin_mail'];
    if(sendmailer($d['mail'],$from,$subject,$msg)){
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM jb_subscribe WHERE id='".$d['id']."' LIMIT 1");$countmail++;sleep($c['subscribe_sleep']);
    } 
}
echo $lang[1074].": ".$countmail;
?>
```

Comment: "Вот вам кусок кода, добавьте сюда картинку!"

А что за картинка, откуда она берется, куда её нужно вставлять ? Ниче не понятно ...

+ что это за функция sendmailer ?

Answer (score 2):

Картинка придет, вто мслучае, если исходник картинки вложить в само письмо.

в конец файла, разделив разделителем письма, задав нужные заголовки:

```
$bound="---Ya_Tipa_RazDelitel---";
$body="--$bound\n";
$body.="Content-type: text/html; charset=\"windows-1251\"\n";
$body.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

$body.="
    Тут некий текст <img src=\"cid:my_pic_img_1\"> Продолжение текста 
    <img src=\"cid:my_pic_img_2\"> - а это вторая картинка
";

$body.="\n\n--$bound\n";
$body.="Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"".basename($file_name)."\"\n";
$body.="Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
$body.="Content-ID: <my_pic_img_1>\n\n";
//сюда зачитывает исходник картинки
$f=fopen($file_name,"rb");
$body.=base64_encode(fread($f,filesize($file_name2)))."\n";
$body.="--$bound--\n\n";
$body.="Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"".basename($file_name2)."\"\n";
$body.="Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
$body.="Content-ID: <my_pic_img_2>\n\n";
//сюда зачитывает исходник картинки
$f=fopen($file_name2,"rb");
$body.=base64_encode(fread($f,filesize($file_name2)))."\n";
$body.="--$bound--\n\n";
```

Это было тело письма.
При этом Content-type письма должен быть: multipart/alternative;

Comment: только не multipart/alternative, а multipart/mixed

То что ты написал несколько другое.

Comment: Идея правильная Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, примерно так:

```
$msg=$c['subscribe_text'];
```

меняем на

```
$msg=$c['subscribe_text'].'<br />какой-то текст<br /><img src="'.$h.'/путь/к/картинке.жпг" />';
```

Пробуйте.

Comment: Молодец Sh4dow. Сразу чувствуется рука профи! Без лишних эмоций.
Кстати страничку с контактами добавил себе в "избранное"! Прошу только подкорректировать свой ответ

    $msg=$c['subscribe_text'].'<br />какой-то текст<br /><img src="'.$h.'images/logo.гиф"/>';

Приходит текст со ссылкой на картинку, А нужно чтобы приходила сама картинка(Ну... логотип).

Comment: Не факт что почтовик разрешает картинки показывать. "<br />" в письме есть или на его месте перенос? + ссылка на картинку верная?

Comment: Высвечивается текст 
.<br />?????-?? ?????<br /><img src="http://www.ввввв/images/logo.гиф"/>

где http://www.ввввв/images/logo.гиф рабочая ссылка на картинку(логотип), при нажатии в новом окне загружается логотип.

Хотелось бы чтобы логотип отображался сразу в письме!!

Answer (score 0):

```
addAttachment($file, 'image/png /*или свой формат*/');
```

нормальные люди делают так. А вот что за скрипт и из какой он админики - это уже к Вам вопрос. Хреново разбираться в чужом коде. А вообще вам надо так же включить в описание функцию sendmailer(). Неужели это доска объявлений?

Comment: Судя по всему, это рассылка в `text/html` и ее хотят "украсить" штоле...